# Create a new named buffer with a function

Tags: buffers, functions

I want to create a keyboard shortcut that will prompt me for a string and then open a new `ansi-term` buffer with that string as the buffer name. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write-up this answer, I first typed `C-h f ansi-term RET` and saw that the `*Help*` buffer let me know that there are two possible arguments, one mandatory being `PROGRAM`, and the secondary optional being `NEW-BUFFER-NAME`.  From there, I wrote the function `my-ansi-term` asking the user to input the `new-buffer-name` (if not provided programmatically), and to ask the user for the `program` name (if not provided programmatically) ... which will default to the same defaults that are included in the original function `ansi-term` if no `program` is specified.  [This information was derived by typing `M-x find-function RET ansi-term RET` and reading the code.]  I arbitrarily chose the keyboard shortcut of the `f5` key.  Inasmuch as the variable `explicit-shell-file-name` is not defined in Emacs 27 until the library `term.el` is loaded, I chose to define it with a `nil` value (which is the default value in the aforementioned library).

```lisp
(defvar explicit-shell-file-name nil)

(defun my-ansi-term (&optional program new-buffer-name)
"Doc-string."
  (interactive)
  (let ((program (if program
                     program
                     (read-string "PROGRAM:  " nil nil (or explicit-shell-file-name
                                                           (getenv "ESHELL")
                                                           shell-file-name))))
        (new-buffer-name (if new-buffer-name
                             new-buffer-name
                             (read-string "NEW-BUFFER-NAME:  "))))
    (ansi-term program new-buffer-name)))

(global-set-key [f5] 'my-ansi-term)
```

Comment: When i input the buffer name "mybuffer" the resulting buffer name is "\*mybuffer\*". is there a way to remove the asterisks from the buffer name?

Comment: Yes, but that would involve a re-write of original function consisting of approximately 20 lines of code without the comments.  In general, most forum participants frown upon rewriting built-in functions because they fear it will potentially incur too much maintenance if the developers modify the base code, and/or they view such modification as taboo / sacrilege.  To re-write the function, just type `M-x find-function RET ansi-term RET` and copy the function and paste it over to your `.emacs` / `init.el` file and remove the asterisks ... perhaps defining `explicit-shell-file-name` beforehand.